# How do I unlock online levels in SMB?

Tags: ps4, super-meat-boy

I've already gotten 20 bandages, but they've apparently changed the unlock requirements. Any ideas of how to unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

Super Meat Boy came out only few days ago for PS4, and usually that kind of game has some bugs regarding achievements and the way to unlock them. Binding of Isaac had similar issues the first days, for example.

On the official wiki page of [Teh Internet](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Teh_Internets) there's this comment:

```
I have over 30 bandages in the PS4 edition and I still haven't unlocked it
```

so I think it's a common issue.

Or simply, they've changed the unlock requirements but there are no hints as of now. Just wait for a fix.

Comment: Funnily enough that comment was me. I've searched low and high.

Comment: @PopCar LOL. It's too soon now, let the Internet another week to understand what's wrong.